# Comparison function returning -1, 0 or +1

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was solving this:

> Write a compare function that returns 1 if x > y, 0 if x == y, and -1 if x < y.

Writing the code, it seemed that after the first `if` statement, either `elif`, `else` and `if` could be used. (I wrote examples on the code comments).

Which one is better and why? (Even if it's just to be closer to the best practices among programmers, I'm just starting out and I'd like to avoid bad habits, thank you!)

```
def compare(x,y):
    if x > y:
      return 1
    elif x == y:
      return 0
    elif x < y:
      return -1

# doubt: Why not use 'if' here instead of 'elif'? like:

# def compare(x,y):
#    if x > y:
#      return 1
#    if x == y:
#      return 0
#    if x < y:
#      return -1

# doubt: Why not make the last statement 'else' instead of 'elif'? like:

# def compare(x,y):
#    if x > y:
#      return 1
#    elif{or 'if'?} x == y:
#      return 0
#    else:
#      return -1

def compare_numbers():
    x = int(input('value for x: '))
    y = int(input('Value for y: '))
    return compare(x,y)

print(compare_numbers())
```

Comment: In Python 2, just `compare = cmp`! It’s since been removed.

Comment: `else` after `return` is redundant. In a non-optimizing compiler it will just generate an unreachable jump. In an optimizing compiler it should do nothing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Select the form of if-else that reinforces your intent**. Your intention in
`compare()` is to make an exclusive categorization: greater than, equal to, or
less than. The appropriate structure for that situation is `if-elif-else`. Even
though, from a narrowly mathematical point of view, one could argue that
`if-elif-elif` or even `if-if-if` would "work" the same way in this particular
case, they convey the wrong message: they imply that some inputs might satisfy
none of the tests and therefore that the function could return `None`. Because
we know how numbers work, we know that won't happen in this specific case, but
you want to select the `if-else` style that reinforces your intent, not a
style that raises new questions. In a case this simple, I would express
`if-elif-else` like this, but that's mostly a code layout preference rather
than a strong opinion.

```
def compare(x, y):
    return 1 if x > y else -1 if x < y else 0
```

**Use a consistent indentation style**. Four spaces or two spaces, not both. In my experience, four is most commonly used and recommended.

**You should be using a main guard and validating user inputs**. [But you already know
that](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/274739/function-that-checks-fermat-s-theorem-for-a-set-of-values).

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you! I'll fix the indent. And I'm not using the main guard or validating user inputs yet because I actually don't undestand it enough. I'm studying everyday and I'll get to this point soon. But I tried to read about it after being corrected and I didn't really understand it, so, as I don't want to simply copy and paste it I'm waiting to get to the point that the book is gonna teach me about those things (I'm very close to it, I just checked the chapters) if you think it's urgent and know any good resource, I'd give it a try, I usually read, but videos are ok too :)

Comment: @pedromartins Fair enough. If I were you, I would just copy-paste the main guard: it's important, but not very interesting, and you'll learn its details soon enough.

Comment: Yes to everything except the double-ternary.

Comment: Significantly, NaN values fall through the last `elif` here, and so will not return a value (arguably `None` could be a good return value, but it should be documented - the other plausible result is to raise an exception).

Comment: @Toby Speight: Not just NaNs; any type with comparison operators that implement a non total order. So for instance `x = {1}` and `y = {2}`, where neither is a subset of the other.

Comment: _"we know how numbers work"_ - perhaps, but 1) we also know that `float` doesn't really behave like any conventional number, and 2) the problem never said `x` and `y` were numbers.

Comment: @Eric Sure, but I think you're ignoring the question context.

Answer (score 5):

Honestly I think what you have is legible and fine, other than replacing the last `elif` with an `else` and fixing indentation - things that FMc has already covered.

An officially-suggested pattern from [What's New in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons) is:

> If you really need the `cmp()` functionality, you could use the expression `(a > b) - (a < b)` as the equivalent for `cmp(a, b)`.)

But on the balance I really do recommend your method over this one, which is tricky and uses implicit bool-to-int magic.

Comment: Note that the suggested `(a > b) - (a < b)` actually implements a different specification: that implements _"a compare function that returns `1` if `x > y`, `-1` if `x < y`, and `0` otherwise"_. This is arguably a better specification, because it still ensures `compare(x, y) = -compare(y, x)` even if the elements are incomparable.